# How to convert ANM files to Maya Acii?

Tags: maya

I had these bunch of maya files on my hard drive. Unfortunately, my hard drive crashed, and I had to give it for data recovery. Now, those maya files got recovered as .anm files.
Is there a way to convert them back to maya ascii or maya binary files? ANM files are described as being "3d Image File"! Those files are very important to me for a project that I'm working on.....
I've really drawn a blank from the intertubes so far.

Thanks in advance,
S

PS : the files belonged to maya 2008 - maya 2010.

Here's a sample:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2AL684G-ov-M3lSU0pueVZyOGc

Comment: Is the format in ascii? If so can you show a sample.

Comment: Description updated with sample link.

Answer (score 1):

As a Maya artist, I've not encountered anm files yet, but according to this site:
http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23480&sid=d2f60eb43548e316a4c563ececccaf28 "A bit of google finds that .anm is a proprietary format which supposedly can be opened in Maya, though even that looks questionable." Have you tried loading the Maya importers under plugins? Have you tried just opening them in Maya or importing it? If not, this may sound silly, but it works for some files, try changning the extension file.anm to file.mb or file.ma and then try opening it.

Comment: I've tried opening/importing them with Maya,but maya does not open them. I also tried renaming them, but no joy.
But I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To import or export them you need to enable the AnimImportExport.mll plugin in you maya plugin manager.

The file format [is documented here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/GUID-91EE8FBF-3267-4A41-BD7B-A2EBA1478F27.htm,topicNumber=d30e246543).  It looks pretty simple.

Comment: That's not the file format I'm looking for. I'm seeking the "ANM" format, not "anim". I can see they are easily mistaken. :)

Comment: Here are some links about the ANM file format:


[ANM File Format](http://filext.com/file-extension/ANM),
[Opening, viewing or converting ANM files?](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1903011.html),
[File extension: ANM](http://www.gillius.org/cg3/anmfile.htm)